# Parsing the pointers in JSON using python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following data in Json which has nested loops. Here the author has a pointer to the className _User.

```
{ "results": [
{
    "accepted": "YES",
    "author": {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "_User",
        "objectId": "HZ1c6AmfuE"
    },
    "createdAt": "2014-02-19T22:39:47.899Z",
    "objectId": "t6G5lLaxoR",
    "recipient": {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "_User",
        "objectId": "avIzy6RtKQ"
    },
    "updatedAt": "2014-02-19T22:40:08.906Z"
},
{
    "accepted": "YES",
    "author": {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "_User",
        "objectId": "HZ1c6AmfuE"
    },
    "createdAt": "2014-02-20T00:18:40.640Z",
    "objectId": "ZmagKJJVKd",
    "recipient": {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "_User",
        "objectId": "zw48k1oAw3"
    },
    "updatedAt": "2014-02-20T00:19:17.602Z"
}] }
```

I use the following code to read the file

```
json_data = pd.read_json('RelationshipRequest.json')
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item, orient='index').T for item in json_data.results])
print df.author
```

This prints :

```
0    {u'className': u'_User', u'__type': u'Pointer'...
0    {u'className': u'_User', u'__type': u'Pointer'...
```

Is there a way where I can extract objectId from the nested field in author to get the author.objectId = HZ1c6AmfuE
?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using `json.load(filename)` or `json.loads(json_string)` and then simply `parsed_json['author']['objectid']`?

Comment: The data you posted is not a valid JSON format. I tried to load it using `json.load` and it failed.

Comment: json.load results in "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'"

Comment: @HaiVu It worked, `>>> json.loads("""{...}""")` gave `{'results': [...`

Comment: My bad: I copy/paste and missed the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Python and JSON works:

Either you save that exact content in a file and use:

```
with open('RelationshipRequest.json', 'r') as fh:
    json_data = json.load(fh)
```

or you pass it as a string directly yourself:

```
json_data = json.loads('{ ... }')
```

Either way, the net result would be (and this is how you access JSON data):

```
for result in json_data['results']:
    print(result['author']['objectId'])
```

Python doesn't treat JSON data as objects, like you're used to in JavaScript, it's a dictionary and nothing short of it so treat for what it is is my suggestion.
There's probably some neat trick to convert this into class objects but this is generally how you actually use JSON data in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you want to accomplish, but if all you want is to extract the **objectId** fields, then the following code snippet will do that.

```
import json

with open('RelationshipRequest.json') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
    id_list =  [rec['author']['objectId'] for rec in json_data['results']]
    print id_list
```